# Bar on the side in latex

Tags: algorithms

I really like the way the algorithm is presented in here:
[image]

I can achieve the internal part, how do I put a bar on the side in that way?

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[brackets]{schemata}
    \begin{document}
    \schema[open]{}{
    {\sffamily VerifyTransaction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textsc{inputs:}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item public parameters pp
        \item a (mint or pour) transaction tx
        \item The current legger $L$
        \end{itemize}
        \item \textsc{outputs:} but $b$, equals 1 iff the transaction is valid 
    \end{itemize}}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\[
\left[
\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: not really the same, but close!